# Why block id is generating with encrypted id

Tags: views, blocks

When I am creating one block view using Views in drupal7 it is creating perfectly but when I am seeing the id using firebug, I am seeing ecrypted id like below.

```
block-views-f4lsdfjiodfofsdfnsdkfbb6213e4c0fece99305
```

How can I remove or override this encrypted value in the id.

Answer (score 9):

Views block deltas aren't encrypted, they just use an MD5 hash. The reasoning is thus:

> block.module has a delta length limit of 32, but our deltas can unfortunately be longer because view names can be 32 and display IDs can also be 32. So for very long deltas, change to md5 hashes.

That comes directly from the comments in [`views_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_block_info/7), which then goes on to run this loop:

```
foreach ($keys as $delta) {
  if (strlen($delta) >= 32) {
    $hash = md5($delta);
    $hashes[$hash] = $delta;
    $items[$hash] = $items[$delta];
    unset($items[$delta]);
  }
}
```

Which, as the comments suggest, make sure that the delta is a maximum of 32 chars.

You can try implementing `hook_block_info_alter()` to implement your own naming convention (it might work, I haven't actually tried it). But the 32 char limitation imposed by the block module is set in stone at the database level so you'll have to take that into account.

If you do that you'll probably need to hook into some other parts of views as well, so that it knows how to process the new block deltas you've given.

As kiamlaluno points out in the comments, you could actually control this at a higher level by making sure that your view's name + display ID together don't exceed 32 characters.

I'm not sure exactly why you want to change this delta, but in my experience the most common reason is so that you can target a specific block with a template file.

Just in case that is your use case, this is a snippet I use in projects to level the playing field so-to-speak.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block']->module == 'views') {
    // Add some template suggestions that are a little easier to manage than
    // the default dom id added by views.
    $delta = $vars['block']->delta;

    $found = FALSE;
    if (strlen($delta) == 32) {
      $hashes = variable_get('views_block_hashes', array());
      if (!empty($hashes[$delta])) {
        $delta = $hashes[$delta];
      }
    }

    list($name, $display_id) = explode('-', $delta);
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__views__' . $name .'__' . $display_id;
  }
}
```

This will let you create a file named like `block--views--viewname--displayid`, regardless of the delta length limit imposed by the block module

Comment: This is exactly the reason of those strange IDs. Did you notice if `$delta` is created from something the user entered when creating the view? If it is so, then there could be a way to control the used ID (e.g. entering a shorter string, when a parameter is requested).

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes it's generated from the view name + display ID (e.g. `articles-block_1` for a view called 'articles' with a block display name of 'block_1'). That's certainly one way of controlling it, good thinking